# Tools/Tips for integrating existing Java SWT projects into WindowBuilder?

Tags: eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

Having recently heard about [Windowbuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) and its excellent graphical tools, I am looking atways to integrate it into a current SWT project.  I would prefer not to start from scratch, though the project has not entered into production, and theoretically has some wiggle room for integration/refactoring time.

The current project uses gridlayout, formlayout, absolutelayout and columnlayout, and uses multiple shells.  Currently UI code and button code have been abstracted into separate classes, so the UI template class can be used to instantiate multiple different shells in the same program.  It is in the process of being integrated with [swt.paperclips](http://code.google.com/p/swt-paperclips/).  The future of this app will include serial port communication, likely through [serialio's SerialPort](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php).

What are the best tools to use to integrate existing code into Windowbuilder using SWT and Eclipse?  Are there any caveats or gotchas that I need to watch out for?  Are there any tools that allow for creation of reusable UI templates, or am I expected to start from scratch with every layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I can give is to download WindowBuilder and try it out.

In my experience, I have found it very capable of parsing my sources and just working with my current SWT code, provided I am using typical SWT, JFace or RCP idioms and not reinventing the wheel.

*Aside: I'm the author of PaperClips so I hope you're having a good experience with it.  :-) Be sure to send a note to our Google Groups forum if you have any questions or problems*

Comment: I have downloaded it and I'm in the process of trying it out.  If something doesn't load, is it hopeless after that?
Speaking of not reinventing the wheel, do you always create SWT shells from scratch, or is there a faster way to get those working?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by creating SWT shells from scratch?  I don't follow you.

Comment: Apparently, I've created a rather unique set of code where the UI method takes the current shell, parent shell, and display as arguments, and then builds the UI in a "UI" class, followed by configuring the UI elements and code that would be executed by button clicks in a sepatate "config" class.  It allows for dynamic generation of the UI and reuse of the same UI template for multiple shells.  WindowBuilder doesn't like it, though, because no one class contains enough information to create a mock-up of the UI.  BTW, PaperClips is pretty cool!  I've filed a bug report or two already.

Comment: Send a small example of your code to the WindowBuilder team.  I suspect they'll be able to accomodate you.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this in the WindowBuilder [FAQ](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/faq.html#CreatedByHand):

**Can WindowBuilder Pro edit windows that have been created by hand?**

> Yes.
>   Most GUI builders in the world will
>   only read and write the code that they
>   themselves create. WindowBuilder Pro
>   is an exception to that rule. It can
>   read and write not only the code it
>   creates, but also a great deal of code
>   written by hand(>90%). If you come
>   across a case that does not work, send
>   it to us for analysis. The more broken
>   examples that we can "fix", the better
>   WindowBuilder Pro will get in the long
>   run (and the better chance you will
>   have of salvaging your old code
>   as-is). Note that dynamic GUI code can
>   not be rendered or edited. The problem
>   with dynamic code is that it generally
>   relies on runtime calculations that
>   have no meaning at runtime. Widgets
>   created in a loop (where the loop
>   parameters are passed in externally)
>   are a good example. Widgets created in
>   conditionals where the value of the
>   conditional is not known until runtime
>   are another example. Dynamic GUI code
>   constructed from the results of
>   complex database queries is yet
>   another example.

Since some of my GUIs are dynamically generated, they don't currently import correctly.

I sent a message to one of the developers on the WindowBuilder project, and they indicated that to make UI templates that can be reused for future use, I can choose to implement [factories](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/features/factories.html).  In my project, this will require some refactoring, but since there still is more coding to do, I might still save myself time in the long run.